# How to add padding, not margin, in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm new to ios development, came from android, Kotlin specifically. So thing is, I'm used that each view has a padding and a margin modifier, margin affecting its outside and padding its inside, but that doesn't seem to apply in SwiftUI.

Does it have a different name? or does swift ui have a different approach concerning padding and margins?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for them in SwiftUI. You can apply multiple `padding`s:

```
Text("Content")
    .padding()
    .background(.white)

    .padding()
    .background(.orange)

    .padding()
    .background(.teal)

    .padding()
    .background(.white)

.border(.gray)
```

[image: Demo]