# How to give inside padding to a Text in swift ui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct MostViewedViewItem: View {
    let moviePic: String = "image_placeholder"
    let movieName: String = "Movie Name Loading..."
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            // TODO: add a navigation link to the movie
        } label: {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Image(moviePic)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 170, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3))
                    .overlay(
                        Text(movieName)
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(height: 30)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background (
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color("lighter_bg"))
                                    .opacity(0.4)
                            ),
                        alignment: .bottom
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm trying to add padding inside the background, so I want the background to be fill the whole horizontal spaace, but I want the text to have some padding, how to do that?

Comment: have you tried something like: `Text(movieName).padding(10)` or `.padding(.leading, 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `padding` **before** the `.background`. Also, you may want to use `frame` `instead` of `scaledToFill` like this:

```
Text(movieName)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(Color("lighter_bg").opacity(0.4))
```

<sub>[Here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76573432/5623035) for better demonstration of applying paddings</sub>

Comment: it doesn't work, the rectangle just bypasses the border when I do that

Comment: That is because of the `scaledToFill`, use `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` instead